# Add event listener of a method present in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am accessing few methods written in another js file. So i'm accessing them like this:

**file1:**

```
function minit() {
  this.addval = function(val1, val2) {
    return val1 + val2;
  }

  function autoexecute(d) {
    //do something here//
    //raise event//
  }
};
```

**file2:**

```
var con = new minit();
var result = con.addval(2, 3);

/*
con.autoexecute(function(d) { //Wanna do something like this
  alert(d);
});
*/
```

Above things are working as expected, getting result..
Now, Suppose `autoexecute(d)` method is invoking automatically after a time interval. How can i know if the method is executed ?

So that, I want to create an event(in file2) of `autoexecute(d)`(in file1).

**UPDATE:**
I hope this example will help you to understand the issue..

company.js *//this is the main file which will be used as a reference in* ui.html

```
function hello(personname) { //this method will invoke automatically after 1 minute..

}
```

ui.html

```
<script src="company.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function bye(personame) { //this method will be called automatically if hello method invoked.... personame is the argument passed from hello method//

      alert("comany.js -> hello function is executed");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to make this clearer to understand.

Comment: Please check i've updated the main thread..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tgjms546/ read it up

Comment: I read. bye will be fire if it will be in the same file where the hello method is. but they are not in the same file... this is the problem. hello() firing automatically by a timer inside the comany.js..

Comment: Where Bye is declared is completely irrelevant so long as it is in the same SCOPE, not file. If Bye is a global function it will fire, 100%

Comment: Yes you are right.. I was doing mistake by declaring bye() inside document.ready... Thank you.. but if bye is inside document.ready, can we use addeventListener to listen the hello() inside the bye()?

Comment: No you cannot. You cannot change the scope of the function in tha manner. You can however declare it like `window.bye = function(){//codehere}` does essentially the same thing. Point is, if you do it that way, why bother putting it in document.ready() anyways.

Comment: I was using document.ready() coz i dint know about the function scope.. Now i don't need of it.. Thanks again for giving your valuable time.. :)

Comment: @Dellirium please reply in answer section so that i can accept that as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if the functions have the same scope (global scope is the best case scenario).  If the autoexecute function has local scope then you cannot to do it.

In essence, override the original function like this...

```
// keep a reference to the original function
var _autoexecute = autoexecute;

// override the original function with your new one
function autoexecute(d) {
    alert("before autoexecute");  // fired before the original autoexecute
    _autoexecute(d);              // call the original autoexecute function
    alert("after autoexecute");   // fired after the original autoexecute
}
```

Now, whenever `autotexecute` is called it will call your new function which can handle both before and after events, as well as calling the original function.  Just remove the (horrible) alerts and replace with event handlers as required.

Comment: @DavidM there is no trigger, there is no event. Any function within the same scope that used to reference the old autoexecute now references the new one.

Comment: Thank you Archer! But how to get the trigger of _autoexecute in file2? autoexecute is the global function... now how can i get it's invoke trigger in file2? as autoexecute(d) is inside the file1..

Comment: The files are irrelevant. Scope is what matters. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, and someone should correct me if I am wrong, there is no way (at least without some library) to detect a function being fired in javascript. Function executions do not fire an event that other functions can 'handle' in that that sense.

In your example you wanted a function to automatically fire after the other function has fired, all you need to do is call the function you want to fire at the end of the one that was "fired" in the first place. Confusing but hope this helps.

```
function handler(){
  alert("main function was fired!");
}
function main(){
  //Code of main goes here and then at the end just add:
  handler();
}
```

Now when your "main" has finished its work it will call upon the `handler` function.

Regardless of where you define the handler function, which can be a different file or same file, so long as it is reachable from within the `main`'s scope, it will be fired at the end of it. It can even be declared after main has been declared, so long as it is declared before main is fired.